# Forward Keberos Ticket with Nginx

Tags: nginx, kerberos

I would like to use nginx as a proxy to an application which authenticates with Kerberos.  Is it possible to pass the keberos ticket through nginx to the reverse proxied application ?  I was hoping for something like:

`proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header  Authorization;`

I am testing with the following script after a valid kinit:

```
import requests
import kerberos
import requests_kerberos

host = '10.200.30.212:8998'
auth = requests_kerberos.HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=requests_kerberos.REQUIRED, force_preemptive=True)

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```